# RGBA, Inverse of alpha compositing with each channel 8 bit size, in C

Tags: c, colors, int, precision, alphablending

Assuming I have two colors, one is *src* and the other is *dst*. They all have 4 channels (RGBA). Each channel is 8-bit size (0x00 - 0xFF).

If *src* is above the *dst*, according to [Alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending), I get the *out* color:

- out_*A* = src_*A* + dst_*A* * (1 - src_*A*)
- out_*RGB* = (src_*RGB* * src_*A* + dst_*RGB* * dst_*A* * (1 - src_*A*)) / out_*A*

So, if I have the composited color *out* and *src*, I can get the *dst* color:

- dst_*A* = (out_*A* - src_*A*) / (1 - src_*A*)
- dst_*RGB* = (out_*RGB* * out_*A* - src_*RGB* * src_*A*) / ((1 - src_*A*) * dst_*A*)

In C, if have to use 8-bit for each channel. I get the alpha compositing code:

```
/*
 * [0] - R
 * [1] - G
 * [2] - B
 * [3] - A
 */
uint8_t src_raw[4], dst_raw[4], composed[4];
float src[4], dst[4], out[4];

/*
 * We get the src_raw and dst_raw color,
 * now calculate the composed color.
 */

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    src[i] = src_raw[i] / 255.0f;
    dst[i] = dst_raw[i] / 255.0f;
}

out[3] = src[3] + dst[3] * (1 - src[3]);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    out[i] = (src[i] * src[3] + dst[i] * dst[3] * (1 - src[3])) / out[3];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    composed[i] = out[i] * 0xFF;
}
```

*inverse of compositing* is the smae but having the *composed* and *src* to calculate *dst*.

The problem is when casting from `uint8_t` to `float`, calculating and casting from `float` to `uint8_t`, I lost the precision.

For example, if `dst_raw = {0, 0, 255, 128}` and `src_raw = {128, 0, 0, 64}`, I get the *composed* color `{51, 0, 152, 159}`. But when `composed = {51, 0, 152, 159}` and `src_raw = {128, 0, 0, 64}`, I get the dst_raw color `{0, 0, 254, 126}`.

My question is: **How can I get the correct dst_raw color when inversing the alpha compositing using 8-bit size to represent one channel?**

Comment: Not sure if it'll help but you should round the conversion, instead of truncating: `composed[i] = (int)(out[i] * 0xFF + 0.5F);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that in general what you want is simply not possible, because there is a loss of precision.

Imagine that your dstAlpha is for example 0x0F, then any destination color value (from 0x00 to 0xFF) will have its range compressed in the output to 0x00 to 0x0F, at best. Then there is simply not enough information to restore the original value.

If from 8 bits you keep only 4, then you will not be able to recover the other 4 from thin air. The lower the alpha the worst the loss of precision.